# jquery get href and text from a tags on a page and show them in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var contentText = $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    async: false
}).responseText;

$("#defaultData").append(contentText);

$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});

//delegate?

var test =  0;  
var href = 0;
var title = 0;

$('.btn').click(function(){


    var href = $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href');
    });
    console.log(href);

    var test = $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).text();
    });

    console.log(test);

$.each(href, function(i, val) {
        $("#data").append(i + " => " + val + "<br/>");
    });

    $.each(test, function(i, val) {
        $("#data").append(i + " => " + val + "<br/>");
    });

}); 
//for (var i = 0; 50; i++) {    
//var pageNum = $("a#specificLink").attr("href").match(/page=([0-9]+)/)[1];
});
```

What this code does:
It gets a page (index.php) prints it, removes the images and gets the href and text from all a-tags.

1st question:
text
should give me: link and text
but it gives me link and link :s
I realy don't get this

2nd question:
Alse I want to append the href and text to a div, seperated by semi colons.
So it looks like this: 
link;text
link;text
...

Now I get:
link
link
text
text
...

Comment: what does contentText contain after the $.ajax call? Could you post this in a jsfiddle or in this question?

Comment: I think that all the code after the ajax call should go on a `success` function inside the object, other than that, idk

Comment: contentText contains just some html with lots of links in a table that part is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all the `link;text link;text`

```
var test = "";
$('a').each(function() {
    test += $(this).attr('href') + ';';
    test += $(this).text() + ' ';
});
alert(test);
```

The reason you end up with link;link;link then text;text.. is because you are processing all links via

```
$.each(href, function(i, val) {
    $("#data").append(i + " => " + val + "<br/>");
});
```

before even processing the texts. Add them at the same time as shown above.

Comment: ok this is also working, thanks guys
I just don't know who I have to check for the correct answer, blly moon or richard, and karim also thanks

Comment: Is it against the rules to tick one of us here - then go and tick a completely separate answer from the other guy 
to even things up?

Comment: I always thought that you could make a good game based around first to answer on stack overflow - or at least an examination system. Fastest accepted answer gets top marks etc...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that $('slector').each() is designed to return values. You should populate a viariable inside the loop like this:

```
var href = []
$('a').each(function() {
    href.push($(this).attr('href'))
})
console.log(href)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, it appears that you're using `.each` the way that [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) should be used:

```
var href = $('a').map(function() {
    return this.href + ';' + $(this).text();
}).get();
$("#data").append(href.join(' '));
```